# Magento 2 call url param in Model Collection filter

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, controllers, model, resource-model

I'm trying to get some data that matches the id in the URL. I have a param in admin URL like below.

```
seller/items/index/id/9/
```

I'm using the admin UI component which is working fine.

My model code below.

```
protected function _initSelect() {        

$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$getId = explode("/",$urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());        
$idString = $getId[9];
//$id = (int)$idString;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
$id = $param = $request->getParam('id');
$this->addFilterToMap('increment_id', 'main_table.increment_id');
$this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');

$this->getSelect();
parent::_initSelect();
$this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id', ['eq' => $id]);

return $this;        
}
```

I'm getting the Id in this model page when I var_dump. But it is not filtering. It is showing zero records, but if I give static id in the condition it works. Seems like the model starts loading before the page rendered.

Answer (score 0):

$this->addFilterToMap('increment_id', 'main_table.increment_id');

$this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');

$this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.seller_id', ['eq' => $id]);

Make sure the id you get is correct